# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when read_csv and skiprows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to read only certain rows in a large pandas CSV file. I managed to create a regular python list (A) with about 600 million row indices that should be skipped when I read this file.

However, when I try to read it using:

```
pd.read_csv(path, nrows = A)
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What could be causing this? that I'm running out of memory or something else with the list type not being the right one in this case?

Thank you

Comment: If you pass `chunksize=100000` and iterate over the chunks does it still happen?

Comment: pandas version?

Comment: current pandas version 0.13.1.

Comment: @EdChum I am trying passing smaller chunks. But the smaller chunks won't mess up with the indices correct?

Comment: It shouldn't do, try it on a smaller file just to check but it would make sense that it should handle this